# Javascript: console.log with colors and objects

Tags: javascript, console.log

I know i can add colors to my JS/TS logging by doing

```
const msg = 'My Message';
console.debug(`%c${msg}`, 'color: green; font-weight: bold;');
```

But how would I log objects in color as well? I tried some experiments

```
const obj = {key: 'value'};
console.debug(`%c${msg}`, 'color: green; font-weight: bold;',obj );
console.debug(`%c${msg}`, ...['color: green; font-weight: bold;',obj]);
```

But they all produce the same weird colorless formatting

[image]

Comment: These are ANSI color escape sequences and are meant for terminals.

Answer (score 1):

just use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it into colorable text

```
const obj = {key: 'value'};
console.log(`%c ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`, 'color: green; font-weight: bold;');
```